# Access db to vb.net combobox

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, combobox

I have been cruising through different forums today, and have watched a few videos on the topic, and continue to have problems so I'm asking here. If it has been answered, I apologize, but it's not been for my lack of looking. I am new to database and programming topics, so my wording or phrasing of the question may not be helpful to me.

Anyhow, I am building an equipment sizing calculator in vb.net, with data being housed in Access. When I come to each new form, I will have a new piece of equipment I am sizing. I have a data grid view set up in each form, and several combo boxes, that will be used for querying the datagrid view. This works fine, I connect to the database fine, but I cannot get the values from my db to populate into the filtering comboboxes. I will post a bit of my code, although I have tried multiple different arguments and methods.

This is how it currently is:

```
Access.ExecQuery("Select Distinct [RegModel] from [tblRegulators]")

If Not String IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then
MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub
End If

cmbRegulators.Items.Add(Access.dbdt)
```

Access is a call to a new class that I made to handle connection to the database, declaring data adapter and data table and a few other things, so that is all handled within access command(Right term?).

Now the way I have gone about this is a bit different than a lot of the examples I've seen today, but it seems a bit better than some of those. When I populate the datagridview, I use a similar logic, except the query is different, and instead of
    cmbregulators.items.add(Access.dbdt)
it is 
    dgvRegulators.datasource = access.dbdt

Now when I do it with the combo box, I get either systemdata.data.rowviews or something along that line populated in the combobox, nothing in the combo box except maybe a slash, and with one line of code I got the regulators listed, but repeating. Now in this case, all rows are distinct, so I don't understand how it was repeating them. I even tried going through the properties of the combobox and pointing the datasource at the specific column of data I want, and I still got the systemdata.data.rowviews from above.

So far I think I have tried:

```
cmbregulators.items.add(access.dbdt)
cmbregulators.itesm.addrange(access.dbdt)
cmbregulators.items.add(access.dbdt.tostring)
cmbregulators.datasource = access.dbdt
cmbregulators.datasource = access.dbdt.tostring
cmbregulators.items.add(access.dbdt.rows.tostring)
```

and maybe a few more. I also have tried declaring a different variable for db connection, and basically starting from scratch to dump the data in, using

```
 cmbregulators.datasource = access.dbdt
 cmbregulators.displaymember = "RegModel"
 cmbregulators.valuemember = "RegModel"
```

and that also did not work. I believe that is the one that got me the repeating values of an already unique set of data, even with using the distinct clause in the query.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or see a problem?

```
Public Class dbControl
'create db connection
Private dbconnection As New       OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;" &
                                            "Data Source=Station Designer.accdb;")

' Prepare DB Command
Private dbcmd As OleDbCommand

'db Data
Public dbDA As OleDbDataAdapter
Public dbDT As DataTable

' Query Parameters
Public params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

' Query Statistics
Public RecordCount As Integer
Public Exception As String


 Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
    'reset query statistics
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""


    Try
        ' Open a connection 
        dbconnection.Open()

        ' Create db command
        dbcmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, dbconnection)

        ' load parameters into db command
        params.ForEach(Sub(p) dbcmd.Parameters.Add(p))

        ' clear params list
        params.Clear()

        ' execute command & fill datatable
        dbDT = New DataTable
        dbDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbcmd)
        RecordCount = dbDA.Fill(dbDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message

    End Try

    ' Close Database
    If dbconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then dbconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

These two subroutines are under the class I created called "dbcontrol" access calls that class. See the first line in the next snippet.

Those two are where the connection adapter and data table are initially declared and then the form's "show" event is where the datagrid view pulls the data in, and it's code is as follows:

```
  Private access As New dbControl
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    ' run query
    access.ExecQuery("Select * from tblInventory")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.Exception) Then MsgBox(access.Exception) : Exit Sub

    'fill datagridview
    dgvInventory.DataSource = access.dbDT
```

Comment: What connection are you using... a OleDbConnection?

Comment: yes : private dbconnection as new oledbconnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0; data source = station designer.accdb"

Comment: The part of your code we don't see and which might be causing you trouble is the function/property `Access.dbdt`. Which type does it return? Could you show us your code? That being said, `ComboBox.Datasource` must be set with an object that implements `IList`. An array (of String, for instance) does it; a whole DataTable does it as well.But in the latter case, you must set '.DisplayMember' as the name of a field that contains meaningful string, or any type which can be cast to string.

Comment: I edited the original post to try to show a bit of the separate class I made for establishing connection and what not. Access is an instance of that separate class, and dbdt is my datatable. I read about the IList earlier, and I'm not sure what all that means. I haven't dealt with arrays much, and honestly feel like there has to be a better way of doing this than doing that. I would think I should just be able to run my query on the database, producing the query as a datatable(dbdt) and then call upon the queried 1 column data table and use it as my source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using an actual connection like this?

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(Yourconnectionstring)
    conn.Open()
    Dim strQuery As String = "Select Distinct [RegModel] from [tblRegulators]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(New OleDbCommand(strQuery , conn))
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    cmbregulators.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cmbregulators.DisplayMember = "RegModel"
    cmbregulators.ValueMember = "RegModel"
End Using
```

Comment: I tried the almost exact code earlier, and it did not work. I will try it again, and report back. However, I did edit the original post to show my code of how the connection is made. if you'd like to review it for errors while I try out this code, I would appreciate that.